# Copying one file to multiple remote hosts in parallel over SFTP

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko, python-asyncio

I want to use Python to copy a local file up to several remote hosts in parallel. I'm trying to do that with `asyncio` and Paramiko, since I'm already using these libraries for other purposes in my program.

I'm using [`BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor) and the default `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which is effectively a new interface to the old `threading` library, along with Paramiko's SFTP feature to do the copying.

Here's a simplified example of how.

```
import sys
import asyncio
import paramiko
import functools


def copy_file_node(
        *,
        user: str,
        host: str,
        identity_file: str,
        local_path: str,
        remote_path: str):
    ssh_client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy())

    ssh_client.connect(
        username=user,
        hostname=host,
        key_filename=identity_file,
        timeout=3)

    with ssh_client:
        with ssh_client.open_sftp() as sftp:
            print("[{h}] Copying file...".format(h=host))
            sftp.put(localpath=local_path, remotepath=remote_path)
            print("[{h}] Copy complete.".format(h=host))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

tasks = []

# NOTE: You'll have to update the values being passed in to
#      `functools.partial(copy_file_node, ...)`
#       to get this working on on your machine.
for host in ['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2']:
    task = loop.run_in_executor(
        None,
        functools.partial(
            copy_file_node,
            user='user',
            host=host,
            identity_file='/path/to/identity_file',
            local_path='/path/to/local/file',
            remote_path='/path/to/remote/file'))
    tasks.append(task)

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
except Exception as e:
    print("At least one node raised an error:", e, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

loop.close()
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the file gets copied up serially to the hosts instead of in parallel. So if the copy takes 5 seconds for a single host, it takes 10 seconds for two hosts, and so on.

I've tried various other approaches, including ditching SFTP and piping the file to `dd` on each of the remote hosts via [`exec_command()`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command), but the copies always happen serially.

I'm probably misunderstanding some basic idea here. What's keeping the different threads from copying the file in parallel?

From my testing, it appears that the holdup happens on the remote write, not on reading the local file. But why would that be, since we are attempting network I/O against independent remote hosts?

Comment: Maybe `paramiko` is using some lock internally. Did you try `ProcessPoolExecutor`?

Comment: @HuazuoGao - I did, but it didn't seem to help. Maybe I did it incorrectly? Taking a quick look at Paramiko's source now, it [doesn't look like](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/0b9d772a21a44af38ecceae0fdbae645e386bd9b/paramiko/sftp_client.py#L595-L639) there is any internal locking going on, by the way.

Comment: I replaced `copy_file_node()` with some dummy code and it worked fine so I thought it was `paramiko` that prevented concurrency. If it's the case, `ProcessPoolExecutor` should solve the problem. Can you post the `ProcessPoolExecutor` version of your code?

Comment: @HuazuoGao - [Here it is.](https://gist.github.com/nchammas/783632df222277605fde) It doesn't seem to help, even if I explicitly set `max_workers` to 2. Am I using `ProcessPoolExecutor` incorrectly?

Comment: I think you did everything right. It really confused me that `ProcessPoolExecutor` didn't work, since tlastowka's answer shows that `multiprocessing` does not has the problem.

Comment: Add `print(threading.current_thread().ident, time.time())` at the beginning of `copy_file_node`, increase # of hosts to 10 and see how many threads you actually have and when their execution start.

Comment: @alexanderlukanin13 - If I add some print statements and leave the number of hosts at 2, I see 2 threads start at almost exactly the same second. One thread terminates in 20 seconds, while the other takes 40 seconds. The file I'm copying takes roughly 20 seconds to upload to a single host using stand-alone `scp`.

Comment: @NickChammas Are you sure network bandwidth is not a bottleneck?

Comment: @alexanderlukanin13 - Yes, because if I copy a smaller or larger file, the transfer to the 2 remote hosts always takes double the time of `scp` to a single host. If bandwidth was the problem, at some point a small enough file should have been able to make it up to both hosts simultaneously.

Comment: @NickChammas Try to copy that file to two hosts manually via scp at the same time and see how long it will take.

Comment: My hypothesis: your OS does not allow concurrent file read. Try using completely separate file for each task (including identity and host key).

Comment: @alexanderlukanin13 - Actually, maybe you are right about the bandwidth. If try 2 separate `scp` processes one always finishes in ~23 seconds while the other takes ~38 seconds. Wow. So maybe nothing is wrong except my assumptions about my own environment... :)

Comment: @HuazuoGao - Good idea. Just tried that. Same results. Would be surprised if that was the case with OS X. On further inspection, problem is starting to look more like a bandwidth one and not a code one.

Comment: @alexanderlukanin13 - Do you want to post the analysis and advice from your comments as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is nothing wrong with your usage of asyncio.**

To prove it, let's try a simplified version of your script - no [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/), just pure Python.

```
import asyncio, functools, sys, time

START_TIME = time.monotonic()

def log(msg):
    print('{:>7.3f} {}'.format(time.monotonic() - START_TIME, msg))

def dummy(thread_id):
    log('Thread {} started'.format(thread_id))
    time.sleep(1)
    log('Thread {} finished'.format(thread_id))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = []
for i in range(0, int(sys.argv[1])):
    task = loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(dummy, thread_id=i))
    tasks.append(task)
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
loop.close()
```

With two threads, this will print:

```
$ python3 async.py 2
  0.001 Thread 0 started
  0.002 Thread 1 started       <-- 2 tasks are executed concurrently
  1.003 Thread 0 finished
  1.003 Thread 1 finished      <-- Total time is 1 second
```

This concurrency scales up to 5 threads:

```
$ python3 async.py 5
  0.001 Thread 0 started
  ...
  0.003 Thread 4 started       <-- 5 tasks are executed concurrently
  1.002 Thread 0 finished
  ...
  1.005 Thread 4 finished      <-- Total time is still 1 second
```

If we add one more thread, we hit the thread pool limit:

```
$ python3 async.py 6
  0.001 Thread 0 started
  0.001 Thread 1 started
  0.002 Thread 2 started
  0.003 Thread 3 started
  0.003 Thread 4 started       <-- 5 tasks are executed concurrently
  1.002 Thread 0 finished
  1.003 Thread 5 started       <-- 6th task is executed after 1 second
  1.003 Thread 1 finished
  1.004 Thread 2 finished
  1.004 Thread 3 finished
  1.004 Thread 4 finished      <-- 5 task are completed after 1 second
  2.005 Thread 5 finished      <-- 6th task is completed after 2 seconds
```

Everything goes as expected, and overall time grows by 1 second for every 5 items. Magic number 5 is documented in [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) docs:

> *Changed in version 3.5*: If *max_workers* is `None` or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine, multiplied by `5`, assuming that ThreadPoolExecutor is often used to overlap I/O instead of CPU work and the number of workers should be higher than the number of workers for ProcessPoolExecutor.

**How can a third-party library block my ThreadPoolExecutor?**

- Library uses some kind of global lock. It means that library does not support multi-threading. Try using ProcessPoolExecutor, but with caution: library may contain other anti-patterns, such as using the same hardcoded temporary file name.
- Function executes for a long time and doesn't release GIL. It may indicate a bug in C extension code, but the most popular reason to holding the GIL is doing some CPU-intensive computations. Again, you can try ProcessPoolExecutor, as it isn't affected by GIL.

None of these is expected to happen with a library like paramiko.

**How can a third-party library block my ProcessPoolExecutor?**

It usually can't. Your tasks are executed in separate processes. If you see that two tasks in ProcessPoolExecutor take twice as much time, suspect resource bottleneck (such as consuming 100% of the network bandwidth).

Comment: And, as you helped me see in the comments on the question, the cause behind the apparent serial upload I was seeing was simply my upload bandwidth!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is the best way to approach it, but it works for me

```
#start
from multiprocessing import Process

#omitted

tasks = []
for host in hosts:
    p = Process(
        None,
        functools.partial(
          copy_file_node,
          user=user,
          host=host,
          identity_file=identity_file,
          local_path=local_path,
          remote_path=remote_path))

    tasks.append(p)

[t.start() for t in tasks]
[t.join() for t in tasks]
```

based on comment, added a datestamp and captured the output from multiprocessing and got this:

```
2015-10-24 03:06:08.749683[vagrant1] Copying file...
2015-10-24 03:06:08.751826[basement] Copying file...
2015-10-24 03:06:08.757040[upstairs] Copying file...
2015-10-24 03:06:16.222416[vagrant1] Copy complete.
2015-10-24 03:06:18.094373[upstairs] Copy complete.
2015-10-24 03:06:22.478711[basement] Copy complete.
```

Comment: I'll give this is try. However, shouldn't this be functionally equivalent to using the `ProcessPoolExecutor` with `asyncio`, [like I did here](https://gist.github.com/nchammas/783632df222277605fde)?

Comment: I'd think so since same basic apis, but without going through the whole source of both, i'd hazard something like "they implement something slightly differently"  

Also, since you're using futures, it begs the question of what *exact* version of python and assorted modules you are using.  The question is tagged 3.x, but futures suggests you're using 2.x with 3.x backports, or an early 3.x, or some other old module.  Its conceivable you're hitting up against strange interaction between module versions / unhandled edge case in the backport. I used python 3.4.3 and recent everything else.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.0 and Paramiko 1.15.3. `concurrent.futures` is what the [3.5 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor) on `asyncio` reference when explaining what executors can be provided to `run_in_executor()`. Anyway, lemme give this a shot and see if there's a difference. When you say it works for you, btw, are you copying a large enough file to 2 remote hosts to notice if they get uploaded serially or in parallel?

Comment: I generated a random 200 meg file with dd.  hosts list was [physical ubuntu 14.04 over lan, a physical ubuntu 15.04 machine over bad wifi ,local vagrant instance running centos 6.5].  They started together, vagrant and local lan finished a few seconds later.  Wifi took longer for obvious reasons.

Comment: Avoiding `asyncio` and trying your `multiprocessing` example doesn't change the result for me. This is killing me. :) Perhaps I should invest in learning how to profile a multithreaded or multiprocess Python program. I'm not sure how else to proceed, or why you are seeing different results.

Comment: For argument's sake, since 2 of your hosts are local (LAN and Vagrant) and thus fast, can you generate a file large enough that it takes 10 seconds to copy to one host? Then try copying it to both LAN and Vagrant at once. Does it still take roughly 10 seconds? The results are more difficult to interpret in your case since you're going to the same disk for both of those hosts. The 2 hosts I'm testing against are identical m3.medium instances on EC2; it takes me 20 seconds to copy a 5MB file to one of them.

Comment: try adding a datestamp to your output or profiling the threads.  because of the way threaded stuff returns, it isn't necessarily printing the output in the same order that it was created in across multiple threads.   You may actually be getting simultaneous transfers and not know it!

Comment: i added some output to my code above.  take a look.

Comment: This is starting to come together. You're probably right that this works, and the original `ThreadPoolExecutor` probably also works. Per the discussion on the question, this is actually starting to look like a network bandwidth problem on my side! Thank you for digging this far with me.

Comment: If its bandwidth, since you're remotes are in ec2, you could always copy it to one of the ec2 hosts and fan out from there to the other ec2 hosts, or send the file to s3 and pull data into the hosts from there.

Comment: Yup, given what the root issue is, those are great suggestions.